# Windows Phone 8.1 App opened

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am doing an app that shows toast notifications, but if the user have the app opened any notification has to be sent.

If I want to avoid show new notifications while de app is opened I should know if the app is being used by the user.

**How can I know if the app is opened in Wp 8.1? (Not running at background, I mean being used by the user in this moment).**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're displaying your notification from a background task just add a flag to the local storage that indicates whether your app is open or not:

```
LocalSettings.Values.Add("IsAppOpen", true);
```

Now all you have to do is to set that flag to true or false whenever your app is:

- activated / launched
- suspended
- resumed

You can use the standard handlers:

```
Application.Current.Resuming += new EventHandler<Object>(App_Resuming);
Application.Current.Suspending += new SuspendingEventHandler(App_Suspending);
```

OnLaunched / OnActivated should already be implemented in your App.xaml.cs. In all those handlers set your flag to the corresponding value:

```
LocalSettings.Values["IsAppOpen"] = true; // Or false, when the app is suspended
```

You can read the flag from your background process and stop displaying notifications.